# Is there a way to install bottle framework for Atom?

Tags: atom-editor, bottle

I have been wondering if there is a way to install Bottle Web Framework for Atom. I have not found a package for it, or at least I don't think I have looked in the right spot and I don't know how to access the pip installer. If anyone could tell me how to get to the pip installer or how to find the package, I'd be very thankful. :)

Edit: I was trying to make a server for my school project for which my teacher recommended that we use bottle. And a lot of places that I went to look for to see how to install bottle just tell me to write in "pip install --user bottle" but I don't know where to put that in. I came here hoping that someone knows how to pull up a terminal on atom so that I can type that command in.

Comment: It would help to know what you're trying to achieve exactly

Comment: I was trying to make a server for my school project for which my teacher recommended that we use bottle. And a lot of places that I went to look for to see how to install bottle just tell me to write in "pip install --user bottle" but I don't know where to put that in. I came here hoping that someone knows how to pull up a terminal on atom so that I can type that command in.

Answer (score 1):

> install Bottle Web Framework for Atom

You don't install Bottle in [atom-editor](/questions/tagged/atom-editor), because Atom runs Javascript, and Bottle is a Python Framework.

> someone knows how to pull up a terminal on atom

You can *edit* Python files in Atom, and you can execute `python` command, but only after you [install a terminal package for Atom](https://askubuntu.com/questions/738157/how-to-open-a-terminal-from-within-atom) will you actually be able to combine the two

> I went to look for to see how to install bottle just tell me to write in "pip install --user bottle" but I don't know where to put that in

*Any* terminal... For example, where you would run `ls` or the `python` command (but not inside the Python prompt itself)

Comment: The last release for Bottle was in Jan 2017, so not sure it's still relevant... https://github.com/bottlepy/bottle/releases

Comment: thank you for your answers, but I still do not know what you mean by any terminal. Because aside from atom I also use codenvy and it automatically has a terminal open for every file that you edit but I cannot seem to find any terminal in Atom. And my mistake i didn't want to download bottle for the whole Atom just for the python file that I am editing using Atom. Thank you anyways for you help.

Comment: Again, "Bottle for whole Atom" is not a thing. Atom is only an editor, for everything, and really has zero connection to Python. I don't know CodeEnvy, but I assume there's literally a panel called *Terminal* because other people have figured it out https://github.com/codenvy/codenvy/issues/1258  AFAIK, CodeEnvy is not running Atom, it's a Web UI based on Eclipse Che